# How to restrict access to multiple apps without authentication using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I have two servers on my aws instance, one is running frontend(vuejs) with nginx and my other app() on a lighttpd server. As of now users can just skip the login and go directly to the app on my lighttpd server by typing it in the url. Is it possible to either render my lighttpd app on to my vuejs app so they cant see it unless they login or redirect to login if they didnt sign in?

I tried to check if the user had a token cookies with nginx before doing a proxy pass to the app but users could just inject or fake a cookie because there is no verification to see if the cookie is valid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the [`ngx_http_auth_request_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html), maybe you could use it to make an auth request to your VueJS app, if the user had a valid cookie, proxy the request to the second server otherwise redirect him to the login page?

Comment: shouldn't your server implement some kind of authentication?  really not sure what you are looking for here, there is no magic

Comment: My vuejs has authentication. I can authenticate into my vuejs app. But the other app is a standalone. It has some scripts and index html. Its not related to vuejs.  The second app im talking about is tar1090 https://github.com/wiedehopf/tar1090 ill go ahead and try that ngx auth request